# How to override function with variable number of parameters in javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, overloading, overriding

I want to override jQuery's `hide()` function on my object. I want it to call my `onHide()` function and then call original `hide()`.

How to accomplish this?

The simplest code won't pass parameters I guess:

```
myobject.oldhide = myobject.hide;
myobject.onHide = function() {
   // something
};
myobject.hide = function() {
   this.onHide();
   this.oldhide();
}
```

jQuery's `hide()` accepts up to 3 parameters. Can I just define 3 of them?

```
myobject.oldhide = myobject.hide;
myobject.onHide = function() {
   // something
};
myobject.hide = function(a,b,c) {
   this.onHide();
   this.oldhide(a,b,c);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `.apply()` to call the original:

```
this.oldhide.apply(this, arguments);
```

which will call `oldhide` with whatever argument list was passed to your own function, which need not have any declared parameters:

```
myobject.oldhide = myobject.hide;

myobject.onHide = function() {
   // something
};

myobject.hide = function() {
   this.onHide();
   this.oldhide.apply(this, arguments);
}
```

Comment: Doesn't `this.oldhide.apply(this, arguments)` will do the same as `this.oldhide(arguments)`?

Comment: @Dims, no.  With the second, `arguments` is passed as the first (`duration`) parameter of jQuery's `hide`.

Comment: Ah, got it, thanks! And on general question, there is no other way to call old version of function other than keeping it in temporary variable?

Comment: @Dims no, the temporary variable is pretty much the only way.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, the ones that are not passed in will just be `undefined`.

Comment: but the code will require changes if a new version of `.hide()` that takes four parameters comes along....

Comment: @Alnitak, only the function definition will change.  The callers of the function don't have to change anything.

Comment: sure, but that's why `arguments` exists - you don't need to declare parameters `a, b, c` solely to pass them on verbatim to another function.

Comment: @Alnitak, agreed.  The main reason would be if they were also used by the wrapper.

Answer (score 0):

You could cache the old hide using [$.proxy](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.proxy/).

```
    myobject.oldhide = $.proxy(myobject.hide, myobject);
    myobject.onHide = function() {
       // something
    };
    //a, b, and c parameters don't have to be passed
    //but if they are they will be forwarded to the old hide.
    //Using $.proxy will preserve the way the old function takes parameters.
    myobject.hide = function(a, b, c) {
       this.onHide();
       this.oldhide(a, b, c);
    };
```

Comment: I don't understand, how parameters for `hide()` will pass to `oldhide()`? For example, if I write `myobject.hide(12);` from my point of view `12` will be lost since `this.oldhide()` does not pass it further. Is it true?

Comment: @Dims I have edited to include information about parameter passing.